# Error manejo de memoria con hilos main: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion

Tags: c++, hilos, manejo-de-memoria

Tengo un problema con el manejo de memoria cuando manejo hilos para realizar el mismo proceso de manera paralela. La secuencia de creación y ejecución de los hilos es la siguiente:

```
    for(i=0; i<cantHilos; i++){
        pthread_create(&hilos[i], NULL, &accionHilo, nombres[i]);
        //sleep(1);      
    }
    for(i=0; i<cantArchivos; i++){
        pthread_join(hilos[i], NULL);
    }
```

La funcion accionHilo es la siguiente

```
char* nombre1 = crearCadena( (char*) argumentos);
Info info = leerInformacionArchivo(nombre1);
```

Y el problema radica en leerInformacionArchivo, en especifico en esta parte

```
while( it < lineas ){
    fgets(linea, 100, archivo);      
    infoAux = crearInfo(linea);
    resultado[it] = infoAux;
    it++;
}
```

Si esta lectura de archivo la hago por separado (secuencialmente) no lanza error, incluso si se hace con distintos procesos, pero cuando la hago con hilos arroja diferentes errores, a veces este

```
main: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

y a veces este simple

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Yo creo que se trata de un error del manejo de memoria con hilos, porque si lo hago con sleep(1) (el que está comentado en el codigo) no se genera este error. Llevo mucho tiempo intentando detectar el error y no he podido

cualquier consejo - indicación es de gran ayuda.

Comment: Pues no crei que fuera necesario puesto que como digo sin hilos el programa funciona sin problemas, pero con hilos parece estarse cruzando las memorias asignadas, la pregunta era un poco mas teorica que practica.

Comment: No tengo variables estaticas, sin embargo me tocó crear una especie de candado para que los hilos no lean la información al tiempo.

Comment: El problema que tienes es que todos los hilos están intentando modificar memoria compartida a lo loco, sin bloqueos ni restricciones. Entonces, dependiendo de cómo se alineen los planetas en cada ejecución, el resultado que obtienes cambia. Usa mutex, semáforos, atomics u otro mecanismo que se te ocurra para delimitar las regiones críticas y evitar así condiciones de carrera y lecturas sucias (que es lo que te está pasando)